# Resizing UIView using UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I have this code which handles the pinch gesture and gets the scale value and passing to the `updateViewBounds` function.

```
func pinchedOnView(gesture : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

        switch gesture.state
        {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:

            self.resizableView.updateViewBounds(scale: gesture.scale , initialBounds: self.resizableView.bounds)

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed :

            self.resizableView.updateViewBounds(scale: gesture.scale, initialBounds: self.resizableView.bounds)

        default : ()
        }
    }
```

So this function takes the input scale finds the corresponding frame and updates the view frame.

```
public func updateViewBounds(scale : CGFloat,initialBounds : CGRect) {

        let zt = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        let tempBounds = initialBounds.applying(zt)

        if tempBounds.width < UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20 && tempBounds.height < UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 20 {

            if tempBounds.height > 300 || tempBounds.width > 300 {
                    self.bounds = tempBounds
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
```

Yeah this function works properly, but it is very fast. Yes as we know that `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` returns each and every fraction of values.

I want the user to see a very proper view resizing, I don't want to update the view for every fraction of value. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you try case `.ended` with  `gesture.state`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to you are scaling the scaled version of the view bound in each sub sequence step using the relative scale respect to the original view bounds.

I think you need to store the initial view bounds of the targeted view at `.begin` and use this value to call the `updateViewBounds`. Another way would be setting `gesture.scale = 1.0` at the end of your gesture handler function.